# Customized container works fine with g++(Rstudio), not fine with MSVS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, rstudio

I have a piece of C++ test code that works fine in Rstudio, which uses g++, but will result in run-time error in MSVS 2012:

```
template<typename T>
struct vec{
    T*head, *tail;
    vec()
    {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }
    vec(int n)
    {
        head=(T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*n);
        tail=head+n;
    }
    T operator [] (int i) const {return *(head+i);}
    T & operator [] (int i) {return *(head+i);}
    ~vec(){free(head);}
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int>y(3);
    y[0]=1; y[1]=2; y[2]=3;
    vec<int>x1(3);
    x1[0]=y[0];
    std::cout<<"vec of integers, [] overloading works fine \n";
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator>z(3);
    z[0]=y.begin();
    z[1]=y.begin()+1;
    z[2]=y.begin()+2;
    vec<std::vector<int>::iterator>x2(3);
    x2[0]=z[0];
    std::cout<<*x2[0]<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"vec of std::vector::iterator, [] overloading g++ works fine, MSVS doesn't \n";
    return 1;
}
```

The code shows if vec contains integers, both MSVS and Rstudio work fine; if vec contains iterators, MSVS will run into the following error:

[image]

I sensed it has something to do with iterators. Could anyone let me know where my mistake is? Btw, I only included the vector header file in MSVS.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post error messages as text and not as images. Also, indent your code, as it is now it is mostly unreadable.

Comment: What's the callstack?

Comment: You wrote your code under assumption that `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a "trivial" object that can be created by a simple `malloc` without any additional initialization. Your assumption is incorrect in general case. Which is exactly why your code fails in Visual Studio. In debug code Visual Studio's iterators are non-trivial objects that require proper initialization by constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating (uninitialized) memory using `malloc` and trying to interpret it as non-POD types like iterators can be. This is bound to fail - `operator=` for an object expects an initialized object as its left operand, but you are giving it a garbage value (hence the crash).

Also, you are not calling your elements' destructors, since you use plain `free`.

A simple solution is to use `new T[n]` in your constructor instead of `malloc` (and `delete[]` in the destructor). This requires your `T` to be default-constructible; there are ways to weaken this requirement (involving placement `new` and some tricks to guarantee alignment).

By the way, your `vec` class does not implement neither the "rule of three" nor the "rule of five", neither disables copy construction, so you are going to have double frees in case your vec object is ever copied.

Comment: Heh, we both saw stuff the other didn't. I think your answer is better, though. +1!

Answer (score 2):

VS has additional error checking baked in to its iterators in debug mode. It found a legitimate bug in your code! The error is that you reinterpret uninitialized memory as initialized objects:

```
vec(int n){head=(T*)malloc(sizeof(T)*n);tail=head+n;}
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

T & operator [] (int i) {return *(head+i);}
                                ^^^^^^^^^

x2[0]=z[0];
^^^^^^
```

The assignment calls `operator=` on the vector iterator object, which is really uninitialized memory, which leads to the crash you're seeing when it tries to interpret some of that memory as valid data. (0xCDCDCDCD, by the way, is what the debugger commonly fills uninitialized memory with to help catch these kind of bugs quicker.)

I suggest using `new`/`delete` instead of malloc. Raw memory allocation is tricky to get right in C++ (where normal memory management is already plenty hard enough).

Note also that in the general case, `malloc` may not yield blocks with high enough alignment for all object types (although it will most of the time, since very few objects are aligned to more than 16 bytes).